# Update duplicate data with same unique-identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table in my database:

[image]

So I want to generate Unique-identifier and Update the UniqueID column as shown below:

[image]

If values of UniqueID are the same, then they must have the same Uniqueidentifier. I have tried to write a CTE as below:

```
;WITH Duplicates AS
            (
                SELECT
                    *,
                    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UniqueID ORDER BY TypeID)
                FROM
                    ##Table1
            )

            UPDATE ##Table1
            SET UniqueID = NEWID()
            FROM Duplicates d
```

But am not getting what am looking for. Very knew to the world of CTEs. What is the best way to get the results am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below - if I understand correctly then you need a `update join`

```
WITH Duplicates AS
(
SELECT distinct UniqueID,NEWID() as nid FROM ##Table1
)
UPDATE a SET UniqueID = nid from ##Table1 a
            join Duplicates d on a.UniqueID=d.UniqueID
```

Comment: I assume your Where clause must be replaced with ON? Says syntax error and also the query is updating with new unique-identifier per row

Answer (score 0):

Below the query for duplicates only:

```
;WITH Duplicates AS
(
    SELECT 
          UniqueID 
          ,Totale = COUNT(*)
   FROM
       ##Table1
   GROUP BY
         UniqueID
   HAVING 
        COUNT(*) > 1
)
,DuplicatesWithRowNum AS
(
    SELECT T.TypeID
   ,RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.UniqueID ORDER BY T.TypeID)
   FROM
       ##Table1 T
       INNER JOIN Duplicates D ON D.UniqueID = T.UniqueID
 )
 UPDATE a SET UniqueID = NEWID()
 FROM
     ##Table1 T
     INNER JOIN D DuplicatesWithRowNum ON D.TypeID = T.TypeID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same value for each `UniqueId`, then use `GROUP BY` to assign the value:

```
WITH ids AS (
      SELECT UniqueID, NEWID() as new_uniqueid
      FROM ##Table1
      GROUP BY UniqueID
     )
UPDATE t1
     SET UniqueID = ids.new_uniqueid 
     FROM ##Table1 t1 JOIN
          ids
          ON t1.UniqueID = ids.UniqueID
```